# How to Click an element with attribute ROLE inside the anchor tag in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to click on an element with attribute role="button" inside the anchor tag using java in Selenium WebDriver? Ex:

```
<a href="#" class="xyz" role="button">
   <span class="ABC">close</span>
</a>
```

I simply want to click on this close button but not using the span text.

Answer (score 10):

Use xpath or css selector

> Xpath - `//a[@role = 'button']`

Css - `a[role = 'button']`

Answer (score -2):

Refer code below,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@role = 'button']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```